# React Material-UI - Styling Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm pretty new to react and i've been at this for several hours, without much luck.

I'm trying to style the Tabs so the underline colour is white:

[image]

and also remove the onClick ripple:
[image]

I suspect it's something to do with overriding the classes: indicator but i'm not entirely sure how / why it works.

I've attached my code for clarity.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react"
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar";

import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab/Tab";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/es/styles/withStyles";

const styles = {
    AppBar: {
        background: 'transparent',
        boxShadow: 'none'
    },
    Indicator:{
        ripple:{
          color: 'blue'
        },
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
};

class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar style={styles.AppBar}>
               <Tabs classes={{ indicator: styles.Indicator}} centered value={0}>
                   <Tab label="Fairness"/>
                   <Tab label="Community" />
                   <Tab label="Referrals" />
                   <Tab label="How To Play" />
               </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

Any guidance / explanation on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Material-UI Tabs, indicatorColor is an `enum: 'secondary' | 'primary'`, but you can [override](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) it with `classes` or with `TabIndicatorProps`. See the [Tabs API](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/) and the [Customized Tabs Demo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/tabs/CustomizedTabs.js), or [mui-org/material-ui/#11085](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11085) for further discussion on this topic.

Here is your example overriding the `indicator` with `classes` for a white underline color and showing how to disable the ripple (note the different `withStyles` import syntax):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar";

import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab/Tab";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/";

const styles = theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
});

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppBar style={styles.AppBar}>
        <Tabs classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }} centered value={0}>
          <Tab disableRipple label="Fairness" />
          <Tab disableRipple label="Community" />
          <Tab label="Referrals" />
          <Tab label="How To Play" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

[image: Edit xk9v99vpz]

Answer (score -1):

In REACT you must use className, not classes.

see this:  https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

You can also look at how they do it on Material-UI site:

https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/

Also when styling in you might not get any errors and the styling will just not be applied.  So sometimes it's tricky to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, your are correct, you should use className on react components. But in this case the prop classes is something that comes with Material UI, not from React, Check out the reference pages: https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: Thanks for that @J.Lindebro i did not know about this.  We learn everyday.